# How to speed up O(n^2) algorithm that checks a graph for parallel edges?

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I have a representative piece of code here that I've been working on to check for parallel edges in a graph.  It is very contrived looking in its current form... What I need help with is just on the algorithm, which is a slow O(n^2) (as best as I can tell), string comparing algorithm.

The real graph is thousands of edges. I'm wondering if there is a faster way to do this.  Note the special case of parallel edges I've created which demonstrates the need for all of that string checking logic.

```
class graph_edge:
    def __init__(self, node1, node2):
        self.node1 = node1
        self.node2 = node2
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s <-> %s' % (self.node1, self.node2)

graph_edges = [graph_edge(('a-1','b-1'),('c-1','d-1')), graph_edge(('e-1','f-1'),('g-1','h-1')), graph_edge(('c-1','d-1'),('a','1-b-1'))]

# check list of edges for any that are parallel
num_deleted = 0
for x, a in enumerate(graph_edges):
    for y, b in enumerate(graph_edges[0:x]):
        if ( ( ( '%s-%s' % a.node1 == '%s-%s' % b.node1 )   and
               ( '%s-%s' % a.node2 == '%s-%s' % b.node2 ) ) or
             ( ( '%s-%s' % a.node1 == '%s-%s' % b.node2 )   and
               ( '%s-%s' % a.node2 == '%s-%s' % b.node1 ) ) ):
            print '(%s)  and  (%s) are parallel' % (a, b)
            del graph_edges[x]
            num_deleted += 1

print '%s parallel edges were found' % ( num_deleted if num_deleted else 'no' )
```

Comment: Hrmm ... might be better suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Use a dictionary. This is an application of an easy rule of thumb: looking for a data structure? use a dictionary! Your key would be pair(startvertex,endvertex). Problem solved.

Comment: More precisely, a `frozenset({startvertex, endvertex})`, since OP obviously wants order not to matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use Hash to check whether it is exist before

UPD1

You can use a `dict()`. For an edge `e`, first check whether it exists in `dict()`, then put it into `dict()`

Dictionary is implemented by hash method

Comment: Thanks for your response, but could you be a little more specific?